# Android listener for onResume() on all applications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I know this could be an issue with security and privacy, but let's assume for now that the user has provided a service with the necessary permissions. The thing my service needs to know is this:

Whenever an onResume() of an activity is called, my service should know which activity was that

Is there any broadcast receiver that I could register? Or does anyone know of any other way?

The idea is as Android has a battery usage application that can break down how much percentage of battery was consumed by an application, I want to capture how much time is a user interfacing with an application, for which I guess I would need to keep track of its onResume calls.

Comment: "Is there any broadcast receiver that I could register?" -- no. "Or does anyone know of any other way?" -- you could write a custom ROM that has an altered version of Android that offers this. Otherwise, you'll have difficulty determining what *process* is in the foreground on current versions of Android, let alone anything finer-grained than that, such as specific activity classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could implement the [Observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). By following it you could think every `Activity` as an Observable (and have the `notify()` method inside the `onResume()` of each of your app's activities) and lastly have a `Service` that works as the Observer. In that case, when the Observer's `update()` method gets called then you know you should do *something*.

Comment: Hi Joaquin, just added an edit to give a clearer idea of what I want to acheive. Is it possible to do via some system provided broadcast if I want to know this for other applications that I have no control over?

Comment: Talk about Broadcasta, Services or whatever else, is out of this discussion. Please check the Observer design pattern and you'll get what I mean. I'm talking you about how to design the system, not about its implementation. Broadcast or Service or whatever you use will work as the Observer. In fact, you could have a BroadcastSender object that is an Observer of the activities and that also knows how to send broadcasts.